# How to pass a variable to the style property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry if the question is phrased with the incorrect terminology.

Basically I want to specify what style I want to change in a function by passing it a variable.

```
function styleChanger(ele, styleProp, x){
      ele.style.styleProp = x + "px";
}

var box = document.getElementById("box");
var height = 100;
var width = 100;
var top = 500;
var styleProp = [height,width,top];

styleChanger(box, styleProp[0], height);
styleChanger(box, styleProp[1], width);
styleChanger(box, styleProp[2], top);
```

I want to do this but its not possible, is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
var styleProp = [height,width,top];
```

I think you meant:

```
var styleProp = ["height","width","top"];
```

If so: In JavaScript, you can refer to a property either using dotted notation and a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, of course, you can use any expression that evaluates to a string, including a variable reference.

So within `styleChanger`, you can use bracketed notation:

```
ele.style[styleProp] = x + "px";
//        ^------- Not the same `styleProp` as above; this one is
//                 the arg to the `styleChanger` function
```

Because of the `styleProp` confusion, here's a complete example with the name of the array changed:

```
function styleChanger(ele, styleProp, x){
      ele.style[styleProp] = x + "px";
      //       ^----------- bracketed notation
}

var box = document.getElementById("box");
var height = 100;
var width = 100;
var top = 500;
var styleNames = ["height","width","top"];

styleChanger(box, styleNames[0], height);
styleChanger(box, styleNames[1], width);
styleChanger(box, styleNames[2], top);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation:

```
ele.style[styleProp] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object instead :

```
 var box = document.getElementById("box");
 var styleProp = {"height": 100, "width": 100, "top": 500};

 for(var key in styleProp) {
    styleChanger(box, key, styleProp[key]);
 };  

 function styleChanger(ele, key, styleProp){
    ele.style[key] = styleProp + "px";
 }
```

Comment: hey Thanks for the comment, is there a reason that this is better then the above answer? Or is it just a different way of doing the same thing. I would like the most efficient way cos I want to do this for animation purposes, if this proves to be better in terms of reuse and speed etc, then it would be interesting to know (more as a OCD of mine to make efficient code).

Comment: @user3012749 For me an object is more appropriate in your case. Because in your code you have a key on one side and the value of the other. If you want to add, for example, the "bottom" key you need to add a variable "bottom", add a string "bottom" in your table and make a call to your function. With an object, you simply add the "bottom" key and its value. For speed, I have no idea, sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

Like @tymeJV and @T.J.Crowder told you, you have to use bracketed notation.
But i've found some bugs in your code. You shall not use the word "top" as a variable name. This may cause erros in some browsers. If you use console.log over your "top" variable in chrome, it will log "Window" not "500" as expected. Also, in the "styleProp" variable, you should use quotation marks, or else, your array will have numbers inside (from your vars) not strings. So, your code should be like that:

```
function styleChanger(ele, styleProp, x){
    ele.style[styleProp] = x + "px";
}

var box = document.getElementById("box");
var height = 100;
var width = 100;
var _top = 500;
var styleProp = ["height","width","top"];

styleChanger(box, styleProp[0], height);
styleChanger(box, styleProp[1], width);
styleChanger(box, styleProp[2], _top);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add another way of approaching this, as well as support R3tep's answer of storing the style changes in an object:

```js
let styleChanges = {
  "#box": {
      "height": "100px",
      "width": "100px",
      "top": "500px",
      "fontFamily": "inherit"
  }
}

let makeStyleChanges = (item, styleProps) => {
  for(let key in styleProps) {
      item.style[key] = styleProps[key];
    }
}

for (let key in styleChanges){
  let item = document.querySelector(el);
  if(item) {
    makeStyleChanges(item, styleChanges[key]);
  }
}
```